# Write resolvers for nested type definitions

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, express-graphql, graphql-tools

Suppose I have following type definition for my GraphQL API:

```
const typeDef = `
    type Book {
         title: String
         author: Author
         likes: Int
    }

    type Author {
         id: String
         name: String
         age: Int
         books: [Book]
    }

    type Query{
         books(authorid: String!): Book
    }
`
```

Then, how many resolvers do I need for this? Should I handle this query request with only one resolver `books` and return all books and author info or should I make many resolvers such as `Query -> books`, `Book -> author` and `Author -> books`? I am not sure how the modular schema and resolver works together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how many type(Book, Author etc) or input you use you need to provide .

```
const schema = ` 
    type Mutation {
        mutatePost(postId:Int) :Int
    }
    type Query {
        hello: String
        posts: [String]
        books(authorId: String!): Book
    }
  `
```

You need to use same name as you defined in Query must be same  in resolver

```
   const resolvers = {
        Query: {
        async hello() {
            return 'Hello';
        },
        async posts() {
            return ['Hello', 'World];
        },
        async books(_, { authorId }) {
            //Return data which you is defined in type Book
            //return Book
        }
        },
        Mutation: {
            async mutatePost(_, {
            postId
            }, context) {
            //return Integer
            }
        },
    }
```

Only thing every Query and Mutation need queryResolver and mutationResolver

Comment: Aren't we suppose to write a resolver for Type `Book -> author` ?

Comment: No need to write resolver for them until you use them in the query or mutation.

Comment: I am using `type Book` and `type Author` as well in the Query return type.

Comment: did you mean books: Book or authers: Author then you need to write resolver for books and authers too.